# Meteor App and Nginx on Port 80

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, meteor, nginx

My site shows always a blank page when I run Nginx on port 80. However if I run Nginx on an other port e.g. port 8080 and I go to mypage.com:8080 it shows my Meteor App. I have no idea why Nginx work on all ports but 80.

Here are my configs.

**Nginx**

```
server {
         listen                *:80 default_server;

         server_name           mypage.de;

         access_log            /var/log/nginx/app.dev.access.log;
         error_log             /var/log/nginx/app.dev.error.log;

         location / {
              proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5000;
              proxy_http_version 1.1;
              proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
              proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
              proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
          }
}
```

**Meteor App started with**

```
sudo PORT=5000 MONGO_URL=mongodb://user:pwd@127.0.0.1:27017/mypage 
ROOT_URL=http://mypage.de forever start -a -o out.log -e err.log main.js
```

**netstat -tulpn shows**

`Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address  Foreign Address   State  PID/Program name

tcp        0   0 0.0.0.0:80           0.0.0.0:*       LISTEN    11214/nginx -g daem
tcp        0   0 0.0.0.0:5000         0.0.0.0:*       LISTEN    10853/node`

but as I said before mypage.de shows blank page... The same configs with Nginx on Port 8080 works. I working on Ubuntu. How can I fix this?

Comment: Can you go to your IP address and attach port 5000 and see your app?

Comment: Yes, when I go to myip:5000 it shows my Meteor app

Comment: Now I tested    sudo python -m SimpleHTTPServer 80  to start a simple HTTPServer, but it shows nothing! When I tested sudo python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8080 and go to mypage.de:8080 it works. It seems like port 80 get blocked or something, but I have no idea why

Comment: I don't feel like we've got enough information for me to give you a definitive answer yet, however check this post out - it has all of the trouble shooting info in it. goo.gl/uQSNX9 . My first step with you would be to change `listen                *:80 default_server;` to just be `listen 80`

Answer (score 0):

Your IP Tables seem to be blocking port 80. That or a firewall in between you and your server.

These are the IP Table rules for web traffic. Just run these commands on the command line:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
```

I would also drop any rules that aren't needed like allowing port 5000. You only want people going to the web ports and that's it.

Comment: It seems that you were right, but I didn't find the reason why the port was blocked. So I ended up to reinstall ubuntu and now it works.

Comment: Hmmm, strange. Glad you got it fixed. A good way to always test if IP Tables is the problem is just to turn them off and see if you can access it. If you can, turn them back on and adjust the rules.